# Basic university textbook without colorful pictures

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations

Could anyone advise textbook(s) with the following properties:

1. No flashy pictures (but with pictures nonetheless; maybe in black
   line).
2. Preferably one column of text (maybe two at max).
3. Good selection of about 10-25 problems that require some thought,
   less mechanical work.
4. Reasonably concise. Perhaps up to 1000 pages.
5. Could be a combination of books (preferably not, but I don't think
   that's necessarily possible).

Basically, I like to zoom in on text, because otherwise I find it hard(er) to concentrate. That's why I like content be presented linearly without random pictures in various unexpected places on the page. If I need more visual representation of something I can go looks elsewhere on the Internet.

Here's what I used for learning calculus that I think is suitable for someone like me http://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/calculus/calculus.pdf
It'd be great if I could fine a book like that for basic university physics.

PS: I don't think I like Feynman's lectures on physics, though.

PPS: I may sound a bit arrogant with the abundant usage of "I", but I think other people could benefit from such a thread, too.

Comment: I don't think the formatting requirements justify having a separate question for this. We already have many book recommendations for introductory physics.

Comment: @DavidZ We do have many recommendations already, but this question is different.  I have the second edition of Halliday and Resnick (1968) on my shelf, and that meets all requirements except perhaps #3.  I frequently use it because it is concise, one column, no distracting boxes and colors, easy to carry (two small volumes).  I particularly appreciate the lack of color and boxes.  I'm able to concentrate more on the content.  But maybe I have ADD.  Mine still has the price stamped on it:  $11.95.

Comment: Look for an older edition of some text. Say 1970s or earlier.

Comment: @garyp okay, but I still think the formatting requirements don't justify having a separate question for this. The answers to other questions, like the linked duplicate, should explain things like the style of the book, so you can tell from that which ones are likely to be the kind of book Max is looking for.